# What is the difference between "gerade jetzt " and "jetzt gerade"?

Tags: meaning, difference, word-choice, usage, phrase

Are both of these equivalent to "right now" or are there specific contexts in which one is more appropriate?

Comment: Please go through the [tour](https://german.stackexchange.com/tour), the [help center](https://german.stackexchange.com/help) and the [asking](https://german.stackexchange.com/help/asking) section to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.

Answer (score 1):

According to my sense of language "gerade jetzt"  = "ausgerechnet jetzt", that is "especially at this moment", "at this very moment".

> - Es sei gerade jetzt besonders wichtig, de Maizière und seine Minister    als Partner auf gleichem Niveau zu behandeln und kein
>     Gefühl der     Diskriminierung aufkommen zu lassen - At this very
>     moment, it is of    utmost importance that de Maiziere ...
> - Gerade jetzt, da Berlin sein    750jähriges Jubiläum feiert. - At the very
>     moment, while Berlin is celebrating its 750 anniversary.
> - Gerade jetzt nicht. - not at this    very moment.

"Jetzt gerade" is actually more like "right now".

> Irgendwas, wo ich mich immer so fühlen kann wie jetzt gerade.

It is important, however, to pay attention to cases where "gerade" doesn't attach to "jetzt" but to a noun or a numeral, slightly changing the meaning.

> - Es ist jetzt **gerade ein Jahr** her, dass sich die Eltern scheiden ließen

However, we cannot treat "jetzt gerade" as a 100% equivalent of "right now" - there may be contexts, where they wouldn't be equivalent.

Comment: What's the difference in meaning between "at this very moment" and "right now"  ?